# How to add my application to the list of applications that can open images?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

When an application on a device tries to share an image, opens a list of applications that can do something with that image: publish it on social networks, edit, etc. What should I add to the manifest file of my application in order to add my application to this list? And, basically, it is interesting what to add to the config.xml in the PhoneGap project.

Comment: its called deeplinking. look into it for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to register your application capable to do certain tasks like open images from storage, you need to add the following code inside the activity tag that can do that task:

```
<activity android:name=".MyImageActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Intent filters inform the system what intents an application component is willing to accept.

You can find more information on the official developer website: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: Thank you, this works, but if you also know how to handle intent (to upload the image which one app will share, to the Canvas in a target app), please, tell me. Cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-intent` gives possibility to handle the Intent, but i don't know how it must be written. How to take the image from intent and put it in to the Canvas on a html page in the app

Comment: If the code has solved your problem, please mark it as an answer so that it can help others as well.

Comment: Regarding your next question, I have not worked with Cordova. But you can receive the data from an intent in your target app pretty easily. Just use getIntent() in onCreate() to access the intent. You can find a working code at https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: `You can find a working code at` - not the same what i need. It is describes how to receive the data in java, but i need to use it in a javascript function. I know, what to use for that (cordova-plugin-intent), but i don't know the syntax, what exactly must be written in a function, how to call that data. My problem is not solved, but your answer is completely an answer to my question how it was asked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look for this url May be it is help you for your solution**

[Open with menu](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event)

Comment: Thank you, but it remains unclear in a part "Do something with the File". What should be added to the `function (Intent)` to upload some `image/*` from this Intent to Canvas in this app? Example will be helpfull

Comment: Just any example, if it possible, where i can see, how to use the data from intent in a JavaScript function. I even can't get how to call this image from intent in a handle intent function